# How to run JSCS on save only (not on keypress) in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor, jscs

I'm using https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-jscs. The docs say:

> It will lint on edit and/or on save

It seems that it lints on edit *and* save all the time. I don't see a way to configure it to lint on *only* save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you really should be looking into moving to ESLint ([linter-eslint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint)) as *all* development on JSCS [has stopped](https://medium.com/@markelog/jscs-end-of-the-line-bc9bf0b3fdb2).

As for your question, you can configure this behavior in the Linter package by disabling On-the-fly linting there. This package is simply a service provider allowing linting of code through JSCS, the Linter package is what controls *when* it is ran, and how its results are displayed to the user.